# create a new div to an existing div of its innerhtml attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been on this issue no head way and have decided to share the problem.
I have a chat application comprising of two divs of different sender as shown

```
<div style="margin-left:8px;" class="bubbledLeft" style="padding-left:5px;" id="chats-container"></div>

<div style="margin-right:8px;" class="bubbledRight" style="padding-left:5px;" id="chats-container2"></div>
```

This is the sample javascript that attaches the text to a div using its innerhtml attribute

```
function fetchAllChats() {
        .....
        xhr.open('GET', encodeURI('/get-all-chats'));
        xhr.onload = function (response) {
            try {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(response.target.responseText);
                    var chats_container = document.getElementById('chats-container');
                    var chats = '';
                    .....
                    chats_container.innerHTML = chats;
                } else {
                    alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
```

My challenge is shown below

```
FromA : hi

             FromB : hello
```

If FromA types **how do you do** again as a response this is what happens

```
FromA: hi
       how do you do
                 FromB: hello
```

You can see that instead of creating a new div and attaching the incoming text below the text that is coming **FromB: hello** it jumps and attaches to the content of FromA. 
Please how do I tackle this squarely using either javascript or css

Comment: Your code isn't creating a new div, it's just getting the first div: `var chats_container = document.getElementById('chats-container')`. Sounds like you want to change this line to create a new div instead.

Comment: Yes that is the challenge

Comment: Did you try any code to do that? Did you find this API? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: you want to create the chat bubble dynamically (allowing for multiple chat bubble)and then append that (with your text in) rather than appending the text into the chat bubbles that already exists (only 2 chat bubbles)

Comment: @Pete yes that is the issue here

Comment: @Riaz you description inserts a new div of document.createTextNode above and not below the div. check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attaching all messages to `document.getElementById('chats-container')`, which is the first div you listed.

What you need to do is check `json[i].user.name` against the logged in user and use the appropriate class for the inner div.

HTML:

```
<div id="chats-container"></div>
```

In your function:

```
var theUser = "Myself"; // replace with logged in user
var chats = '', theClass;
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    theClass = json[i].user.name == theUser ? "rightBubble" : "leftBubble";
    chats += '<div class="' + theClass + '"><strong>' + json[i].user.name + ':</strong> <span>' + json[i].message + '</span></div>';
}
document.getElementById('chats-container').innerHTML = chats;
```

Result:

```
<div id="chats-container"></div>
    <div class="leftBubble">...</div>
    <div class="rightBubble">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: simply awesome and intuitive

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for `appendChild` function:

`chats_container.appendChild(<<THE NEW CHAT MESSAGE DIV>>);`

Comment: appendChild -  the contents dissappeared

Comment: TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.

Comment: The appendChild takes a document element as a parameter.

See the following fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rdf1e0qm/

Comment: base on your fiddle explanation, this is what I am doing but it is not working chats.appendChild(chats_container);

Comment: What I understand is that you want to do the other way around.
The chats should be appended into the container.
`chats_container.appendChild(chats);`

Comment: I have actually tried that before your fiddle demo. Still did not work

Comment: If you are appending the chats as HTML elements represented in strings, then try `chats_container.innerHTML = chats_container.innerHTML + chat;` Where chat is the new chat message

Comment: it is creating a repeatitive loop rather

Comment: Yes in this case you will only need to fetch the new message not all the chat message history.

If you want to separate all the messages after fetching them, you need to keep track of their timestamp, sort them accordingly, and iterate over them to get each one appended to the chats_container in the way mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: That means your solution is not complete then, how do I filter the new message